# maven surfire plugin exclude a package

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing

i tried to excluse a package from test cycle using surfire plugin.
Tests path is: test/java/com/dir1/subdir1/

```
    <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/<subdir1>/*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

but i see always log with all test executed. What is my mistake?

Comment: Why would you like to exclude tests?

Comment: At least surefire plugin should be upgraded - thats quite old version.

Comment: have you tried `**/subdir1/*.java` instead of `**/<subdir1>/*.java`?